# Как правильно указать регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

нужно проверить на php вводимый email адрес, чтобы указывали только .com или .ru остальные адреса не пропускались.
Понимаю что preg_match

```
$str = '';
$isMatched = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$-](?=.*[rzd]).*$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($isMatched, $matches)
```

Comment: Вот тут  `.*$` попробуйте добавить `.*\.(?:ru|com)$`

Comment: попробовал, не получается

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tRxkVe/1 странно что не получается, должно все рабоать, единственное у вас вот тут `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$-]` что то странное, в примере на regex экранировал первый символ `]` думаю еще ключ `m` нужен  для работы символов начала и конца строки

Comment: Как вариант /^[\w\-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+(?:com|ru)$/

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!